# Convergence in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let {${\textbf{x}_k}$} be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*i)* Prove that if {${\textbf{x}_k}$} converges to ${\textbf{x}_0}$, then {${||\textbf{x}_k}$||} converges to $||\textbf{x}_0||$. Prove that converse is not true.

*ii)* Suppose that {${||\textbf{x}_k}$||} is monotone. Prove that if {${\textbf{x}_k}$} is bounded, then {${||\textbf{x}_k}$||} converges. Does {${\textbf{x}_k}$} converge as well?

I can solve this problem in real numbers but have trouble solving it in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: For ii), call $a_n =||x_n||$. Then $x_n$ bounded means $a_n$ is bounded. Can you finish?

Comment: $\{x_k\}$ usually denotes a set; for a sequence, it's $(x_k)$.

Comment: @Gary thanks for the hint! I did finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point : $|\|x_k\|-\|x_0\||\leq\|x_k-x_0\|$, can you continue from here ?
For the counter example, regard $(-1)^n$ for example.

For the second point : you can show that $\|x_k\|$ converges to $\sup_k \|x_k\|$. For the counter example, regard $(-1)^n(1-\frac{1}{n})$ for example (if you want strictly increasing, otherwise $(-1)^n$ does the job)

Comment: a followup question for part a. Is there a counterexample if the x_0 is equal to 0 vector?

Comment: @abbasly Take each coordinate of $x_k$ to be $(-1)^n$ and each coordinate of $x_0$ to be $1$.